# How to add comma seperated string values in dictionary type session variable

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am using c#

I have got below string in my variable.

```
string results = "Mr,Mike,Lewis,32,Project Manager,India";
```

Now I want to add these values in Dictionary type of session variable. I have declared a dict type variable in my code.

```
Dictionary<string, string> skywardsDetails = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Write now what I have written code was like below:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(results))                                            
{                                                
    string[] array = results.Split(',');
    string title = array[0];
    string firstname = array[1];
    string lastname = array[2];
    string age = array[3];
    string designation = array[4];    
    string country = array[4];    

    //Here I want to write the new code which will add the results.Split(',') values in my Session variable as a Dictionary type.                                       

    foreach (string key in results.Split(','))
    {
    skywardsDetails.Add(key,//What to do here)
    }
}
```

Please suggest

Comment: It should come as I have given in array, I mean first one will be title, and second will be firstname so...on

Comment: I think you want to use a `List` instead of a `Dictionary`.

Comment: I would prefer to have dictionary type of session variable.

Comment: @MKS: We then come back to Jon Skeet's question, what do you want it to contain? If you had an ID for each employee I'd suggest making a `Dictionary<int, EmployeeClass>` where the key would be the ID and the value would be a class containing all the values from the csv data. But since you don't have an ID I'm not sure what you want?

Comment: @MKS: Btw, if you prefix your comments with the name of whomever you're responding to, they'll get notified, so if you want to respond to my comment, prefix it with `@ho1` and I'll get notified that you've responded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your CSV `results` variable doesn't represent a dictionary. It represents an `Employee` model:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
var tokens = (results ?? string.Empty).Split(',');
if (tokens.Length > 5)
{
    var employee = new Employee
    {
        Title = tokens[0],
        FirstName = tokens[1],
        LastName = tokens[2],
        Age = int.Parse(tokens[3]),
        Designation = tokens[4],
        Country = tokens[5]
    };
    // TODO: do something with this employee like adding it
    // to some dictionary, session, whatever
}
```

Comment: Thanks so just we have to write to add in session is Session["SkywardsDetails"] = employee, what you suggest

Comment: @MKS, yes `Session["SkywardsDetails"] = employee;` would be nice as it allow you to later fetch it back from the session.

Answer (score 1):

You cant really use foreach here and instead of declaring local variables replace that part with

```
    skywardsDetails["title"] = array[0];
    skywardsDetails["firstname"] = array[1];
    skywardsDetails["lastname"] = array[2];
    skywardsDetails["age"] = array[3];
    skywardsDetails["designation"] = array[4];    
    skywardsDetails["country"] = array[5];
```

Now move those string constants to some constant like const string Title="title" and you will be able to get required field data from your dictionary like

```
string title= skywardsDetails[Constants.Title]
```

Answer (score 1):

It would make more sense to use the dictionary like this:

```
skywardsDetails.Add("Title", array[0]);
skywardsDetails.Add("FirstName", array[1]);
// etc.
```

You shouldn't use the actual values as keys, as i think you want a generic way to access them.

Comment: Thanks @Botz3000, this is the simple solution

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
enum UserData
{
    Title,
    Firstname,
    Lastname,
    Age,
    Designation,
    Country  
}
//========================================================
string results = "Mr,Mike,Lewis,32,Project Manager,India";
string[] array = results.Split(',');
var skywardsDetails = new Dictionary<UserData, string>();
// maybe you need some check data here
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    skywardsDetails[(UserData)i] = array[i];
}
```